# What is the difference between 1:[ ] and [1]? How would you implement : and [ ] in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

What is `:` ? Is it an infix value constructor ?

What is its definition?

I cannot really find the source code for `:`.

Also, what is `[ ]` ?

Is `[1]` defined as a simple
algebraic data type? If yes, how ?

Is it something like `data [a] = a:[ ] | [ ]`  ?

This is just my guess. I'm not sure.

What is the source code for `:`  and `[ ]`?

Are these constructs hard-coded into the compiler?

Let's call `:` as `cons` and `[ ]` as `Nil`. Using these names how would you implement the equivalent of `:` and `[ ]` in Haskell ?

Comment: The [x,y,z] syntax is syntactic sugar built into the language. Technically you _could_ define a constructor named `:` in your own code, but the language actually forbids it. You _can_ use any operator other operator starting `:` as a constructor though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:` is a List constructor function.

```
λ> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
λ> 3 : [2,4]
[3,2,4]
```

`1:[]` and `[1]` are the same. In the first form, you have applied the function `:` to create `[1]`.

`[]` is used to denote empty list. Another usage of `[]` is as a type constructor. This is used for creating instances of `Applicative` etc.

Actually, when you write something like `[1,2,3]`, it is a syntactic sugar for `1:2:3:[]`.

Thanks to @ManuelEberl, you can find the source [here.](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/src/GHC-Types.html)

You can create your own List using `Cons` and `Nil` like this:

```
data MyList a = Nil | Cons a (MyList a) deriving (Show)
```

It just takes a recursive structure to define it. Some demo:

```
λ> Cons 3 Nil
Cons 3 Nil
λ> Cons 3 (Cons 3 Nil)
Cons 3 (Cons 3 Nil)
```

Let me create a function named `constructMyList` which will resemble `:`:

```
constructMyList :: a -> MyList a -> MyList a
constructMyList x y = Cons x y
```

It's demo:

```
λ> let a = Cons 2 (Cons 3 Nil)
λ> constructMyList 1 a
Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Nil))
```

Comment: But how is the list datatype defined? what is [ ] ? What is the source code for `:` ?

Comment: Datatypes are a language feature. They enable you to define arbitrary algebraic data types. The definition of the list type in the source code is `data [] a = [] | a : [a]`. You can find it here: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/src/GHC-Types.html The first `[]` is the type constructor, the second one the value constructor for the empty list. You could define your own list type as `data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)`.